# Install Aptana Studio3 plugin on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, aptana, pydev

I have OS X Lion, Eclipse 4.2.1, PyDev 2.7.1 with all updates applied.
Trying to install Aptana Studio 3.3.2 Eclipse plugin but when I try (http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install), I get the following error. 
Do I need to uninstall PyDev first?
Thanks!

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.3.2.201302081500-7G7F17UIS_IYK7UrNh8biKtz0dax (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.3.2.201302081500-7G7F17UIS_IYK7UrNh8biKtz0dax)
  Software currently installed: PyDev for Eclipse 2.7.1.2012100913 (org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.7.1.2012100913)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Pydev Extensions 1.5.5.2010030420 (com.python.pydev 1.5.5.2010030420)
    Pydev Extensions 2.3.0.2011121518 (com.python.pydev 2.3.0.2011121518)
...several more lines like these, clipped...
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.3.2.201302081500-7G7F17UIS_IYK7UrNh8biKtz0dax (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.3.2.201302081500-7G7F17UIS_IYK7UrNh8biKtz0dax)
    To: com.aptana.pydev.feature.feature.group [2.7.0.2013012902-7g9I-8Jez0cez0LZfI]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Pydev 2.7.0.2013012902-7g9I-8Jez0cez0LZfI (com.aptana.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.7.0.2013012902-7g9I-8Jez0cez0LZfI)
    To: com.python.pydev [2.7.0.2013012902]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: PyDev for Eclipse 2.7.1.2012100913 (org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.7.1.2012100913)
    To: com.python.pydev [2.7.1.2012100913]
```

Comment: I'm no expert but I would try uninstalling PyDev, installing Aptana, then attempting to update PyDev.

Comment: @Sarah-Kemp - that appears to have taken care of it, thank you!